# Identical MAC Addresses on Network

Tags: lan, mac-address, duplicate

I have a network wired connected heatpump with a static IP address on my LAN, my son's Nintendo Switch has an identical MAC address.
Even though it connects via Wi-Fi from an access point, it refuses to connect to the internet. I can get it to see the local network and it appears briefly in the access point log but will not connect out to the internet. It would seem impossible to alter either bit of kit's MAC address.

Any ideas how I can get them working?

I have turned off MAC filtering but all that achieved was enabling the Switch to connect to the network, it could not make the next step to the internet.

Update: The MAC in question is 98:e8:fa:53:c1:01 and is the same on both the Nintendo Switch and the Nibe Heat pump. I keep all my permanent devices locked on static IP addresses (from a reserved list) and hardwired back to the router, there is a uplink to my wireless Access point (Ubiquiti) which then serves both main and guest WiFi networks with its own DHCP server function using a specified range not used anywhere else on my networks. I had thought that giving the switch its own static IP address might work but although it appears in the WiFi log it refuses to connect and it looks like the MAC id takes precedence over the static IP address I assigned it.

@Tonny, the VLAN option might work as the Ubiquiti has this capability, although I have never explored it before - so will give that a try, wish me luck. Otherwise I agree with you about changing the NSwitch although it is over three months since we got it (this Christmas was the first time we tried the internet connected aspect of it) so Currys may not play ball. (Sorry for the duplication of the question but the original was not showing up on my account and was very hard to search for every time.)

Comment: That is wired. The first three octets of a MAC address identify the manufacturer and should be different (I assume the heatpump was not manufactured by Nintendo). Would you mind adding the MAC address to your question?

Comment: @dirdi The manufacturer of the network chip that is. It is certainly possible that both devices use a chip from the same manufacturer, but a double mac-address shouldn't happen. It is not unheard of though.

Comment: The Nintendo Switch on my LAN has the OUI of 5C:52:1E which is indeed registered to Nintendo.  I suspect there's some other problem here, and that the MAC address conflict isn't really occurring.

Comment: Can you show us the arp table dump on your router?  Or photos of the switch and heatpump showing their hardware MAC addresses ?   Some evidence would help enhance this question.

Comment: if the switch was purchased from a reputable retailer they may let you exchange it for another.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1124249/ajax) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1124251/ajax). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: A duplicate question: https://superuser.com/questions/1513107/identical-mac-addresses-on-network-updated --- I copied new information from it here.

Answer (score 9):

Use a router to create a second subnet for your heatpump (or alternatively, for the Wi-Fi devices). MAC addresses are only relevant within the same L2 network they're on.

If you insist on having everything on a single subnet, the only other option which could help is a switch/bridge with "layer-2 NAT" function, placed like a firewall between the heatpump and the rest of the network. For example a Linux software bridge could probably achieve this via 'ebtables', and most Mikrotik RouterOS devices have L2 NAT under '/interface bridge nat' as well.

Without doing either of the above, trying to keep both devices in the same subnet will be nearly impossible, as every single switch or Wi-Fi access point will be constantly changing its mind about where to deliver the packets, and whenever they get delivered to the wrong device it will kill the unrecognized TCP connection (which is normal behavior).

(Note: Even with two subnets, if you try to do this using VLANs, it can still cause trouble if the network switches don't have IVL...)

Answer (score 5):

If they really have the same MAC (which is weird and shouldn't happen, but it isn't unheard of) they conflict with each other at the ethernet level.
Your switches/routers and AP's (and whatever else connected to your LAN) can't distinguish between those devices (as the MAC is the unique ID at ethernet level) so traffic intended for them gets mixed up.
(MAC filtering doesn't have anything to do with this, as you already found out.)

If you can't change the MAC at device level the ONLY solution is to put them in separate LAN's or VLAN's. Unfortunately most SOHO equipment doesn't have VLAN capability.

If your router/AP allows the use of a Guest WIFI that has a different IP-range than the main network try to put the Nintento Switch on that Guest Wifi. With a little bit of luck that Guest Wifi is also a separate VLAN and that would fix the problem.

If the Switch is still under warranty it might be possible to switch it at the store for another one which should have a different MAC.

Comment: Guest WiFi networks always have a separate subnet _(at least that I'm aware of)_, else firewalling that traffic from LAN becomes more complex than necessary since both are on the same CPU ethernet port _(Guest networks are virtual LANs, but lack VIDs and PVIDs)_.  Also, provided a SOHO router is supported by opensource firmware (OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Tomato, etc.), it'll have vLAN support _(opensource firmware should be flashed if available anyways, else the router becomes an unpatched security risk once the device model reaches it's EoL 1 - 2yrs from the OEM's initial release)._

Comment: @JW0914 Separate ip subnet yes, but there are plenty of cheap devices that don’t really vlan and throw everything in single L2 lan. I even have seen some routers that supported a DMZ but still had only a single L2 LAN. If you have one of those it isn’t going to help with the duplicate MAC issue.

Comment: `and shouldn't happen` - MAC address allocation is only designed to be absolutely unique within geographical regions. It's not accurate to say it shouldn't happen - it's more accurate to say that if you buy all your equipment from the same country then it shouldn't happen - the system was never designed for purchasing some of your equipment form overseas

Comment: @slebetman this is wrong. A UAA should be unique world-wide. LAA is set by the sysadmin and needs only be unique locally. [This PDF](https://standards.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-standards/standards/web/documents/tutorials/eui.pdf) contains the rules.

Comment: @vidarlo Note that that is the 2017 guideline which recommends MAC addresses to be globally unique. In the late 90s (an maybe even earlier) manufacturers commonly reuse MAC address for different regions. Western Digital sold equipment with duplicate MAC address in Europe and the US. Netgear also used to sell equipment with duplicate MAC addresses in Asia and the US. I remember facing this issue with a pair of Netgear NICs. There were rumors that some companies even reused MAC addresses for different regions of the US.

Comment: @slebetman: When I was in college around the year 2000, the old greybeard told the story of getting two cards with the same MAC address. His answer seems to be the most correct: RMA *both* of them as defective.

Answer (score 2):

All sorted, Nibe UK passed the problem to their head of Technical and they arranged for a new mainboard to be sent over and fitted, all fine now :) for whatever reason the original board had the same MAC as the Nintendo Switch, the new one doesn't - possibly the "Heart of Gold" was passing over when I installed the kit :)
Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A: I'm assuming, same IP not same MAC, you should be able to change this yourself by changing the static IP on the heatpump.

B: There is no way you have identical MAC addresses, unless this networked heatpump is created by you (hardware wise) in which case, it looks like it copied the first MAC it found on your network... What this means, is thta you need to go back to the heatpump's network card/hardware, and reconfigure it... 
Clarification: Each device's MAC address contains the vendor ID, so unless:
You have identical hardware (still rare)
Are modding the MAC address (you should know how to fix it)
Used custom networking hardware (RTFM)
Using same vendor for both devices (still rare)
You can't have a collision unless its something you did.

C: The last option, is to install DD-WRT, here with some commands you could create something that can "rename" the MAC address incoming on a certain port.

This isn't a complete answer, it's just what I would think of as I research ways to resolve this.

Comment: "There is no way you have identical MAC addresses" - I disagree. It happened at my employer, for example, that due to bad user interface design in our MAC address generator, and the people who normally do this being on sick leave, holiday leave, and paternity leave, respectively, we produced 12 devices with the same MAC address, of which no less than 6 went to the same customer. I also heard a story from a student dorm in my town, where an American and a Chinese exchange student whose PCs had the same MAC address happened to live on the same floor. They both had NICs from a widely-used Asian

Comment: It would be extremely freakishly improbable for the heat pump to use the MAC of the same particular Nintendo Switch that they have in the house.  The Nintendo Switches are probably guaranteed to have unique MAC id's.  So think about it, how improbable it would be? even if all the heatpumps from that manufacturer used identical mac id's to each other, it would be freakishly improbable that it would match with this particular nintendo switch.

there's probably something else going on where either device is using a dhcp lease they shouldn't be using anymore or something like that.

Comment: Its a shame that my sentence was taken apart like that. There is no way to have a collision of MAC addresses from two different vendors. Unless Nintendo makes networked heatpumps...