# Identical MAC addresses on Network updated

Tags: networking, mac, duplicate

I have a network wired connected heatpump with a static IP address on my LAN, my son's Nintendo Switch has an identical MAC address.
Even though it connects via Wi-Fi from an access point, it refuses to connect to the internet. I can get it to see the local network and it appears briefly in the access point log but will not connect out to the internet. It would seem impossible to alter either bit of kit's MAC address.

Any ideas how I can get them working?

I have turned off MAC filtering but all that achieved was enabling the Switch to connect to the network, it could not make the next step to the internet.

Update: The MAC in question is 98:e8:fa:53:c1:01 and is the same on both the Nintendo Switch and the Nibe Heat pump. I keep all my permanent devices locked on static IP addresses (From a reserved list) and hardwired back to the router, there is a uplink to my wireless Access point (Ubiquiti) which then serves both main and guest wifi networks with its own DHCP server function using a specified range not used anywhere else on my networks. I had thought that giving the Switch its own static IP address might work but although it appears in the wifi log it refuses to connect and it looks like the MAC id takes precedence over the static IP address I assigned it.

@Tonny, the Vlan option might work as the Ubiquiti has this capability , although I have never explored it before - so will give that a try, wish me luck. Otherwise I agree with you about changing the NSwitch although it is over three months since we got it (this Christmas was the first time we tried the internet connected aspect of it) so Currys may not play ball : (Sorry for the duplication of the question but the original was not showing up on my account and was very hard to search for every time).

Comment: See if, using this Nintendo article, you can change its MAC address:  https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22397/~/how-to-find-a-nintendo-switch-consoles-mac-address  . The MAC address is found as follows "The Nintendo Switch console's MAC address will be listed under System MAC Address"

Comment: `Sorry for the duplication of the question but the original…` – [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: VLAN is a good way to isolate one device away in its own virtual network where it will not conflict with the other device. Have you advanced in this direction? What is your router's exact model? Are both devices connected via WiFi?

Comment: according to http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt, that's the NSwitch which is using the correct MAC: 98-E8-FA   (hex)  Nintendo Co.,Ltd

Comment: You can still alter the Nintendo MAC address if you do not wish to start into VLANs

Comment: Unfortunately John the Nintendo Switch only lets you view its MAC address in settings not alter it, at least nowhere I can find, the linked article just show where to find it. The Nswitch is on a separate Wifi network from the wired heat pump although they all share the local LAN so will try a) a VLAN setup or b) plead with the shop staff for a swap.