# How will EUI-64 handle MAC Address collision?

Tags: networking, ipv6, mac-address

IP Address generation in IPv6 uses EUI-64, a technique that basically uses the MAC address to calculate the host part of the address. This seems fine as long as it is used for the link local address but you can also set it up to auto-generate the host part of the global unicast address using EUI-64.

I am wondering what will happen in case of two interfaces having the same MAC Address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the interfaces belong to different links (i.e. they don't contact each other on layer-2), this is not an issue. Regular IP routing is done on the entire 128-bit address, not just on the interface identifier, so machines on different networks can perfectly well use the same interface ID. For example, thousands of hosts have manually configured addresses ending with the same `:0:0:0:1`.

If two interfaces on the *same link* (e.g. same Ethernet) have identical MAC addresses, hosts generating their IPv6 addresses from EUI-64 will detect collisions during Duplicate Address Detection (which is mandatory in IPv6) and will mark the address as unusable.

**Note** that IPv6 has been phasing out the usage of EUI-64 for address generation for a long time, in favor of [RFC 7217 "opaque" interface identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7217.html). IPv6 implementations using RFC 7217 use unique seeds when generating the interface ID, so collisions will usually not happen at all.

But aside from IPv6, the actual layer-2 network will be very confused by duplicate MAC addresses. Modern Ethernet isn't a broadcast network – instead, Ethernet switches and bridges keep track of which MAC addresses were seen on which physical ports, and the switch will send the Ethernet frames through only one port at a time (the one where the address was seen last). The result is that all protocols will see packet loss because the Ethernet frames were delivered to the wrong device, *regardless* of what IP address they use.

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE guarantees that MAC addresses are globally unique.  The first half of a MAC address is an "Organizationally Unique Identifier" (OUI) that is assigned to only one vendor, and each vendor is required to make sure they never reuse the second half of the MAC address. When a vendor ships more than 2^24 (~16.8 million) Ethernet-like interfaces, they just request an additional OUI.

Since the EUI-64 is derived from the MAC address in a way that preserves that uniqueness, there won't be a collision.

Temporary/Privacy IPv6 addresses are of more concern, as the host part of those is randomly generated. However, it's a 64-bit field, and the chances of two hosts on the same LAN randomly picking the same address out of 2^64 is astronomically low, unless their PRNGs are super broken.

Comment: The IEEE guarantees that the OUI prefix is globally unique, but it's [up to the manufacturer](https://seclists.org/nanog/2010/Apr/347) to guarantee that the whole address is also globally unique... assuming they even use [the correct OUI prefix.](https://superuser.com/questions/1512439/identical-mac-addresses-on-network)